# Converting all text to lower case in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, lowercase

I have a textfield in my iOS app where the user is supposed to input some text. But I was wondering if there is any way to convert the users input to lowercase letters.

I remember in C# it was something like `Convert.ToLower` but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in Objective-C.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

There is a method called `lowercaseString` on `NSString`. `NSString` contains plenty of methods for string manipulation, please read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello, World!";
NSString *lower = [myString lowercaseString]; // this will be "hello, world!"
```

Comment: Or `myString.lowercaseString` in case you need to be someplace

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:

```
let upperCasedString = "UPPERCASED"

let lowerCasedString = upperCasedString.lowercased() 
//prints "uppercased"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a specific `Locale` when converting a string to lowercase, use `lowercaseStringWithLocale` (`lowercased(with: Locale)` in Swift 3+).

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello, World!";
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSString *lower = [myString lowercaseStringWithLocale:locale];
```

**Swift 3+**

```
let myString = "Hello, World!"
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
let lower = myString.lowercased(with: locale)
```