# Storing each char from a text field in an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble  trying to store input from a textfield into an array where each character is at a separate index.

I have tried storing the input as a string so I can make it all upper case and remove white spaces, but this is causing me problems too.

I figured once it is stored I could just loop through each letter and add each char to a mutable array.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't do this because not every character is 1 in length. Use [stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet or stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608420/how-to-remove-whitespace-in-a-string) and [lowercaseString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693741/converting-all-text-to-lower-case-in-objective-c/8693767#8693767).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  NSString *string  = textField.text;
  NSMutableArray *theArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) 
  {
    [theArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[string characterAtIndex:i]]];
  }
}
```

I would do the storing once the user has ended his/her editing.

Comment: It says error, Implicit conversion of 'unichar' (aka 'unsigned short') to id is disallowed with ARC :/

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the  [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) you can find number of good methods from this delegate which might be useful for your tasks.

There is a method from this delegate which is called every time user press a key in `UITextField`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
 //assuming dict is declared NSDictionary
 [dict setObject:[yourTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] forKey:@"KEY"];
}
```

Comment: I'm the UITextfield Delegate, how could I make that an array?

Comment: it is better to use `NSDictionary` that way you know the keys also `NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dict setObject:someValue forKey:@"A-Key"];`

Comment: okay I'll just try the below code first and then post my code